# Data in not going inside Log Table

Tags: c#, postgresql, serilog

I'm using `Serilog.Sinks.PostgresqlNuget` package to write `lon` inside the `PostgreSQL`  but its not writing any log

```
IDictionary<string, ColumnWriterBase> columnWriters = new Dictionary<string, ColumnWriterBase>
{
  {"message", new RenderedMessageColumnWriter()},
  {"message_template", new MessageTemplateColumnWriter() },
  {"level", new LevelColumnWriter(true, NpgsqlDbType.Varchar) },
  {"raise_date", new TimeStampColumnWriter() },
  {"exception", new ExceptionColumnWriter() },
  {"properties", new LogEventSerializedColumnWriter() },
  {"props_test", new PropertiesColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.Text) },
  {"machine_name", new SinglePropertyColumnWriter("MachineName", PropertyWriteMethod.Raw) }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad to say that i fond the issue
It was because of additional column which i have added in my table (Id Auto increment)
https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Npgsql/3.0.0-beta0001/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/Npgsql/Npgsql/NpgsqlBinaryImporter.cs?ImageName=Npgsql
Now its working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

This code isn't supposed to write any log data. This Code is part of initiating and  registering your logger.

```
string connectionstring = "User 
ID=serilog;Password=serilog;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=logs";

string tableName = "logs";

//Used columns (Key is a column name)
IDictionary<string, ColumnWriterBase> columnWriters = new Dictionary<string, ColumnWriterBase>
{
    {"message", new RenderedMessageColumnWriter() },
    {"message_template", new MessageTemplateColumnWriter() },
    {"level", new LevelColumnWriter(true, NpgsqlDbType.Varchar) },
    {"raise_date", new TimeStampColumnWriter() },
    {"exception", new ExceptionColumnWriter() },
    {"properties", new LogEventSerializedColumnWriter() },
    {"props_test", new PropertiesColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.Text) },
    {"machine_name", new SinglePropertyColumnWriter("MachineName", PropertyWriteMethod.Raw) }
};

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.PostgreSQL(connectionstring, tableName, columnWriters)
                    .CreateLogger();
```

**And after that you can write a log with something like this:**

```
logger.ForContext("Context", "test")
                .Warning("THIS IS A WARN");
```